# Hibernate executeUpdate performance

Tags: hibernate, orm, jdbc

I'm comparing the database "Update" performance between the old way and using Hibernate.

This is my database structure: Document -> Code -> Code_Details.  There is a one-to-many relationship between the parent tables and the children tables.

Now I have about 850 Code_Details entries that I need to update in database.

Below is the old way, which is performing twice as fast:

```
public void executeDBUpdate(int status1, int status2, int status3){
...
...
java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("update Code_Details set status1="+status1+", status2"+=status2+", status3="+status3");

...
}
```

Below is the Hibernate version:

```
public void executeDBUpdate(int status1, int status2, int status3){
...
...
Query query = session.createQuery("update Code_Details set status1=:status1,   status2=:status2,status3=:status3);          
query.setParameter("status", status_);
        query.setParameter("status1",status1);
        query.setParameter("status2",status2);
        query.setParameter("status3",status3); 
        query.executeUpdate();
        HibernateUtils.commitTransaction("emscribedx");

...
}
```

Please note that in both versions my "executeDBUpdate(int,int,int)" method is being called 850 times to execute each database update.

The total time to execute those 850 updates the old way is:

```
954 milliseconds
```

The total time to execute those same 850 updates with Hibernate is:

```
1979 milliseconds
```

I broke it down and noticed that most of the time in Hibernate version is taking in "query.executeUpdate()" -> 954 milliseconds and "hibernateTransaction.commit()" - > 750 milliseconds.

How can I improve the Hibernate performance when executing a lot of updates?

Comment: So, most of the difference is caused by the fact that your Hibernate version commits transaction after each update, right?

Comment: yes. I noticed that in Hibernate version most of the time takes in executeUpdate() and commit() for each update.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I'm now calling the "query.executeUpdate()" 850 times within the same transaction and it really reduced the processing time.
So basically "query.executeUpdate()" gets called 850 times but session.commit() gets called only once.